# Do any Christian groups refer to God as "she", "it" or "they"? (Or is it always "He"?)

Tags: gender, political-correctness

In this age of “Political Correctness”, it seems that many people now frown upon the use of *he* as a gender-neutral pronoun with which to refer to the Christian God, though it was universally used for centuries before the women’s liberation movement of the 1960s. Julian of Norwich and Hildegard of Bingen both referred to “Mother God” in the Middle Ages, but there seem to be no other notable examples throughout history.

Are there any traditions which avoid the wrath of those who object to male-dominated language and refer to the Christian God as *she, it* or *they*? Or is God always male and *he*?

Comment: Christisns generally don't mind if you refer to God as "he"; they're really not that much into political corrrectness or gender-neutrality.

Comment: This question asks about domain-specific language and is more suited to a domain-specific SE site, since there is one. I've adjusted it to make it even more fitted here (and probably should have edited it here rather than on ELU -- sorry about that).

Comment: A key point is that the Bible refers to God as "He" and never "She".  This applies to the Father, Son and Spirit.  True Christianity has always run counter to secular philosophies, and it always will.  It should not be changed to accommodate non-Christian biases.  It is not ours to tell God what gender He is.  It should be noted, though, that God's masculinity is not biological.  The Son did become a Man biologically, but even the Son's masculinity was before His incarnation.

Comment: Starting from the snarky assumption that the only reason a church might move to gender-neutral pronouns is to "avoid the wrath" of "Political Correctness" doesn't seem like a good way to solicit a real answer to the question.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock There are 2.4 billion Christians in the world, are you speaking for all of them?

Comment: All generalities are false. Shame on me for saying "in general". Now we have counter-examples. Two churches who prefer to refer to God in gender-neutral terms. I wonder how they might render Genesis 1:27.  Or explain "mine only begotten son" if God is genderless. And I wonder whether members of these churches would mind if I continue to refer to God as "He". Which is all I said.

Comment: @Narnian: what do you mean, God's masculinity is not biological?  Is he sort of a supernatural Ken doll, masculine but without private parts?

Comment: "Many people" in this context = 1% or less of the overall population of the West.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock That is a ridiculous statement.  What I'm saying is that God existed before the creation of the Universe.  He is spiritual--not physical.  God did not have a physical body until the incarnation.  As such, His masculinity was not defined by any design of a physical body.  If gender is merely physical, then God would have to have a physical body to be masculine.  It seems, though, that masculinity is not merely physical.

Comment: You're absolutely correct that gender transcends biology; spirits have gender before, during, and after dwelling on Earth. What I wonder is what makes you call it "ridiculous" to think God would have a physical body). The Old Testament tells us that He spoke face to face with Moses. Job said (Job 19:26) "And though after my skin worms destroy this body, yet in my flesh shall I see God". After we are resurrected we shall have perfect, uncorruptible bodies, of a different kind (not of flesh and blood, because that is corruptible)

Comment: That is, we shall have perfect, uncorruptible bodies, of a different kind of "flesh", but in the same image as our spirits , which were created in the image of God.  This is the type of physical body that God has—immortal and perfect.

Answer (score 6):

At least two churches have decided to abstain from referring to God exclusively as "he".

The [United Church of Christ](http://www.ucc.org/worship/inclusive-language/).

> The Eleventh General Synod instructed that a Book of Worship be developed and characterized by language that is truly inclusive with respect to God and to people. Although the generic use of masculine terms has been accepted practice, it is exclusive and viewed as offensive by many. Further, the use of only masculine nouns and pronouns for God and of masculine generic terms for humankind has hidden the rich feminine imagery for God and God's people in scripture. Scripture contains many gender neutral metaphors for God such as shepherd, rock, or Holy One. The rediscovery of the complementary female and male metaphors in the Bible and the literature of the early church encourages Christians not to settle for literary poverty in the midst of literary riches.

And the [Metropolitan Community Church](http://mccchurch.org/).

> Many of us, when we first come to MCC, are so accustomed to using male pronouns for God that even when we come to understand God as beyond gender and other human categories, even when we come to view God as Spirit who is neither male nor female, it is still difficult not to say "he," "him," and "his" for God. This male terminology, however, limits God to our cultural view of the Divine, which is a male-dominant point of view.
>
> *~Reverend Dr. Jeffrey Pulling, "More Than Just Words: A Study & Reflection Guide to the Issues of Inclusive Language Within MCC"*

---

*[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_God_in_Christianity)*